# How to determine if file was added/removed/modified from an svn  patch file

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, subclipse

How can I determine whether a file was added, removed, or modified from an svn patch file?

My patch looks like this:

I want to know the test.js and PageCacheCommand.java, two documents is new? Modified? Delete?

```
### Eclipse Workspace Patch 1.0
#P feilong-sitemanager
Index: src/main/webapp/scripts/test.js
===================================================================
Index: src/main/java/com/jumbo/shop/web/command/PageCacheCommand.java
===================================================================
--- src/main/java/com/jumbo/shop/web/command/PageCacheCommand.java  (revision 47766)
+++ src/main/java/com/jumbo/shop/web/command/PageCacheCommand.java  (working copy)
@@ -1,34 +0,0 @@
-package com.jumbo.shop.web.command;
-
-import java.io.Serializable;
-import java.util.List;
-
-public class PageCacheCommand implements Serializable{
-
-   private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 59168831084794622L;
-
-   private List<Object[]>      skus                = null;
-
-   public PageCacheCommand(List<Object[]> skus, Long count){
-       this.skus = skus;
-       this.count = count;
-   }
-
-   public List<Object[]> getPagination(){
-       return this.skus;
-   }
-
-   private Long    count   = 0L;
-
-   public Long getCount(){
-       return count;
-   }
-
-   public void setCount(Long count){
-       this.count = count;
-   }
-
-   public List<Object[]> getSkus(){
-       return this.skus;
-   }
-}
```

Comment: looks like deleted; but there's no way to distinguish between file deletion and making it empty

Comment: i also want to know how to explain "@@ -1,34 +0,0 @@"

Comment: `@@ -1, 34 +0,0 @@` basically says: _Lines 1 thru 34 became lines 0 thru 0_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the ability to use the command line, you can use:

```
svn diff --summarize
```

The output will give you an overview of the changes in the current directory of your working copy.

It will indicate whether files were added, deleted, modified, etc...

To run it on a specific file, add the path to the file.

For example:

```
svn diff --summarize src/main/java/com/jumbo/shop/web/command/PageCacheCommand.java
```

---

To answer your other question...

`@@ -1,34 +0,0 @@` basically means: *Lines 1 thru 34 became lines 0 thru 0.*